# How do I add text to a image in Node Canvas?

Tags: discord.js, image-manipulation

So I have been looking all over the discord.js docs and tried to make a profile card with image manipulation, but for some reason the text comes up as little boxes.  Here is the code:

```
      if (message.content === `-profile`) {\
        const Canvas = require(`canvas`);
        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./image.png');
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.font = '100px sans-serif';
        // Select the style that will be used to fill the text in
        ctx.fillStyle = '#34ebc9';
        // Actually fill the text with a solid color
        ctx.fillText(message.author.displayName, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.8);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();

        const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
        ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

        message.channel.send(`Your profile, ${message.author}!`, attachment);
    }
```

The image shows and my profile picture shows and everything, but for some reason the text either doesn't show, or it is all messed up.  Please help.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Examples of the failed images?

Comment: Yes I get `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file`.

Comment: Ensure that the code is looking for the correct file. It appears that it can't load the configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Device maybe doesn't have any default file that Canvas is looking for. You need to install these fonts manually by yourself, you can get some from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/).

Import the fonts you installed to your Files and use [registerFont()](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#registerfont) to register and use the fonts

```
//Assume you imported your font in your main folder
const { registerFont, createCanvas } = require('canvas')
registerFont('./comicsans.ttf', { family: 'Comic Sans' })

const canvas = createCanvas(500, 500)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.font = '12px "Comic Sans"'
ctx.fillText('Everyone hates this font :(', 250, 10)
```